# filter in array doesn't work properly for me in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of children that sits within one group, I tried to delete a child, and in addition to deleting him from the list. the deletion of the child is done well, but the child is not removed from the list in the group.
The data in MongoDB
The code in NodeJS.
I tried at first to delete the child with getByIdAndDelete() but I saw that after the child has been deleted the Node can't find it because it is deleted.
It seems the filtering doesn't work
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for the help

NodeJS code:

```js
router.delete("/delete-child/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Child.findOne({ _id: id })
    .then((result) => {
      Group.findOne({ _id: result.group }).then((resp) => {
        resp.childrenList = resp.childrenList.filter(
          (childId) => childId !== id
        );
        resp.save().then((savedResp) => {
          console.log("deleteChild", savedResp);
        });
      });
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  Child.findByIdAndDelete(id).then((deletedChild) => {
    console.log("deletedChild", deletedChild);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When MongoDB automatically creates an _id, it is of type ObjectId.

In many Mongoose functions, such as `Model.findByIdAndDelete` a string argument is automatically cast to ObjectId.

In many other functions, there is no automatic cast.  There is definitely no automatic cast in a non-mongoose function such as `Array.filter`.

This means that even if `Child.findOne({ _id: id })` retrieves the correct group with a string instead of ObjectId, `(childId) => childId !== id` won't match.

To fix this, explicitly cast `req.params.id` to an ObjectId with:

```
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
```